# How to resolve juju error when bootstrapping myk8s on Windows 10

Tags: proxy

I am on Windows 10 Home using WSL 2. After installing Docker Desktop, I followed "https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/" to install kind and start a cluster. Now I am following "https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/install" to install KubeFlow. However, I cannot get past step 3 due to the following error.

```
...
Contacting Juju controller at 10.96.56.249 to verify accessibility...
ERROR unable to contact api server after 1 attempts: dial tcp 10.96.56.249:17070: i/o timeout
```

After looking around a lot for answers, it seems to be a proxy issue. However, I don't know how to resolve it. Please advise how to resolve this error.

Comment: Have you confirmed the address of the WSL2 instance is 10.96.56.249?

Comment: That address is generated by juju. I have tried this several times and the address is different each time. This seems to be the address of the Juju controller, not the WSL instance.

Comment: I do understand that the controller is running within the WSL2 instance that means the WSL2 instance needs to have been assigned the proper address

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you for explaining. I did not know that. How do I assign the proper address to the WSL 2 instance?

Comment: Easier to set the Juju IP address to the current address of the WSL2 instance, unless you have a script that assigns the address when the WSL2 instance is started, the IP address won't be static.

Comment: Okay, so it is not that the WSL2 instance needs to have been assigned the proper address, rather that Juju needs to be given the address of the WSL2 instance. Is this correct?

Comment: How do I get the IP address of the WSL2 instance?

Comment: Which command do I need to modify to include an IP address: "juju add-k8s myk8s"; "juju bootstrap myk8s my-controller"; something else?

Comment: How do I modify the correct command to pass in an IP address?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/shayne/go-wsl2-host) might be useful.  Otherwise, [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4210), indicates switching the configuration of the Hyper-V Virtual Switch might be another option.  I am not entirely sure the source of the script, so it's while crude, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1667893/powershell-script-cannot-find-wsl2-instance) appears to allow traffic on whatever the address of the instance might be.  **I know nothing of juju but I can't imagine it the address of the controller cannot be configured.**

Comment: Thank you, I will try this route. I don't know much about networking, so it may be a short road.

Comment: There is no networking knowledge required just basics of configuring Linux